# OCR on PDF using Asprise with Java

Tags: java, ocr

Hye There I am new to this work I am getting this error while compiling my code:

```
     OCR ocr = new OCR(); 
     PDFReader reader = new PDFReader(new File("C:\\Users\\pc\\Downloads\\chk1.pdf")); 
     reader.open(); // open the file.  
     int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages(); 



     for(int i=0; i<pages; i++) { 
      BufferedImage image = reader.getPageAsImage(i); /////null pointer exception here
      System.out.println("OCR result:\n" + ocr.recognizeCharacters(image));  
     } 

      reader.close(); // finally, close the file.
```

The error is:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.Invoke.a(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.as.a(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.as.b(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.as.a(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.gV.a(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.G.l(Unknown Source)
at com.asprise.util.pdf.PDFReader.getPageAsImage(Unknown Source)
at file.tracker.threads.PDFFilerConverter.gotoRead(PDFFilerConverter.java:94)
at file.tracker.threads.PDFFilerConverter.run(PDFFilerConverter.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can somebody help me out getting rid out of it please!

Comment: what else should i provide?

Comment: the full log , the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for(int i=0; i<pages; i++) { 
     String txt =reader.extractTextFromPage(i);
     System.out.println(“Text result:\n” + txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vitalik, which version of the OCR SDK are you using?

I would suggest you try the new Asprise OCR SDK version 5, which should solve your problem. Sample code:

```
String s = ocr.recognize("C:/test.pdf", -1, 100, 100, 400, 200, 
  Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_TEXT, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
```

You may access the [download page of Asprise OCR SDK for Java](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-for-windows-mac-linux-download.html) here.